# Google Maps API doesn't work on live site

Tags: php, google-maps

```
function getlatlang($location,$region)  
{  
    $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($location) .'&sensor=false$region='. urlencode($region));  

    $output= json_decode($geocode);  

    return $output->results[0]->geometry->location;  
}
```

This is what I have been using whilst developing on a local-server, now I've made the site live via my webhost, this no longer returns the location.

Not sure what could be wrong with it?

Comment: is `file_get_contents` returning anything ?

Comment: also key=API_KEY is missing, but you may of removed that to demo

Comment: @Dagon I didn't have any keys setup, the only things I needed that for was google+ access tokens. This code above worked fine prior to uploading the files to a webhost.

Comment: back to the first question then -- (`echo $geocode;`)?

Comment: `$region=` is that a typo?

Comment: @Dagon sorry for the late reply, had problems with the server. $geocode dumps `bool(false)`

Comment: @Engerlost It looks like it, I've amended that and hasn't made a difference.

Comment: are the fopen wrappers enabled on your host?

Comment: @Dagon I'm probably going to assume not, is it possible to enable them? I'm hosted with iPage

Comment: if not, then switch to curl() - hope they have that

Comment: @Dagon Switched the curl() works now, thanks Dagon.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getlatlang($location,$region)  
{  
    //$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($location) .'&sensor=false&region='. urlencode($region));

    $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($location) .'&sensor=false&region='. urlencode($region);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $geocode = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo curl_error($ch);
      echo "\n<br />";
      $contents = '';
    } else {
      curl_close($ch);
    }

    $output= json_decode($geocode);  

    return $output->results[0]->geometry->location;  
}
```

My webhost didn't allow fopen, switched to curl().